# Перезагрузка почти всей страницы

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть такая штука - музыка на яндексе. Так вот, при прослушивании музыки, если ввести другой адрес, принадлежащий тому же яндексу, музыка играет, страница перезагружается вся, кроме конкретно одной области. Может ли кто описать, с помощью чего можно реализовать нечто подобное ( Ajax? ) Ну, и примерчиком коротеньким порадуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам сейчас пишу полностью ajax приложение. Для реализации той же задачи что и у Вас использую HTML5-History-API. Ссылка на [гитхаб](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API). Там всё понятно описано. Даже вроде бы по-русски) Надеюсь помог.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите внимательнее, у вас страница все время одна и та же, адрес в браузере меняется через [history api](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=javascript+history+api), а все остальное грузится через ajax.